# C# getting my program to run on a .Net 1.1, win XP system

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, filesystemwatcher, .net-1.1

So I've made the program on windows 10 Visual studio Version 10 in c# as a console application. The program is just monitoring file changes with fsw. I'm now faced with the challenge of doing literally everything in my power to not have to install anything on the PC of which this program will have to run (as in company they don't normally like us installing anything on the old pc's). So I believe I need to compile the program in a lower version of .Net if possible?
Any help regarding the matter would be appreciated as most things I find is people wanting to move from 1.1 to higher versions or the odd reference to web applications or c++.
Also, (though it may be obvious) I'm not a coder, not even my job really and thus I am quite inexperienced so any answers dumbed down a lot would be incredibly useful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: .NET Core self-contained apps can even run on Windows 3.1 (with certain hacks), so you probably should use that (though totally unsupported on end-of-life systems like Windows XP).

Comment: Is visual studio 10 capable of creating Self contained .Net apps? I've seen the option to publish with it on later versions but not any easy way in VS 10? @LexLi

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if .Net framework is installed if you have not already, and in that case what version it has.

According to [.Net version and dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies) windows XP does not include any .Net version. That page also include links on how to check version. The last .net release for windows XP is .Net 4.0. See [.Net system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements).

So there is no indication that you should use .Net 1.1. Either you would use whatever version is installed, or you install some version you want (i.e. the highest supported), or you do not install any version, and do something else.

Modern versions of Visual studio allow targeting of .Net framework from 2.0 and onwards. And I'm fairly sure you can run .Net 2.0 and later version on windows 10 if you install the framework. Using .Net 1.1 would probably require you to use windows XP as the development system, so I would avoid this if at all possible.

I would recommend using a virtual machine for testing, since it allows you to test on windows XP on your machine, and makes it easy to revert any failures. I would probably recommend migrating the entire PC to a virtual machine it at all possible, since this would reduce magnitude of hardware failures, and make backup and restoring much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Unfortunately I certainly wouldn't get the permission to go upgrading the framework as its all old systems used for running machines and they wouldn't risk having a program  no longer work and upon checking in regedit I found the target system is definetly .Net 1.1. I can't virtualise the machine either as its running at all times so I don't have the permission to do so however I do believe I have a different winXP virtual software so might have to as a last resort try to install VS10 on there. Though first I will look into making it self contained.

Comment: @Simpson Joshua It sounds like the company does not have proper backup procedures for the machine. And that seem incredibly risky if it is business critical. Probably not your problem however.

Comment: I have previously made a winXP virtual machine before and would consider using that however upon further research, VS2010 no longer supports anything before 2.0 framework? The closest I've found to anything that can is vs2005 with MSBEE but thats getting to a real work around and I've read that althoough you can look and run code, it can't compile? Which would be the whole purpose. Would you happen to know of any way of making a framework program self contained or am I looking at a now complex job of converrting to core? @JonasH

Comment: .net framework always needs installation as far as I know. I would not think converting to .Net core would be very complex since the code would mostly be the same, probably easier than dealing with .Net 1.1.